# Не работает передача параметра в директиву Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, angular-directive

На страничке есть календарь от Angular - md-datepicker с такими параметрами:

```
<md-datepicker
     tzoned-date
     ng-model="objt.datesince"
     timezone="objt.timezone"
     md-placeholder="Start Date"
     ng-required>
</md-datepicker>
```

Код директивы

```
.directive('tzonedDate', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            var toView = function (val) {
                var momentd = moment.utc(val).utcOffset(attrs.timezone);
                return new Date(momentd.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            };

            var toModel = function (val) {
                return moment(val);
            };

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(toView);
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(toModel);
        }
    };
})
```

Собственно проблема в том что параметр времени в директиву передается нормально, а вот параметр временной зоны (timezone) всегда передается пустым (пробовал и так писать **timezone="{{objt.timezone}}"**) Результат одинаковый.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил вот такое решение:

```
.directive('tzonedDate', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            model: "=ngModel",
            timezone: "=timezone"
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            var toView = function (val) {
                var momentd = moment.utc(val).utcOffset(scope.timezone);
                return new Date(momentd.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            };

            var toModel = function (val) {
                scope.model = moment(val);
            };

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(toView);
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(toModel);
        }
    };
})
```